# In Outlook, my quick-steps default to font size 10, but my default font settings are set to 11. How to fix so that they use my default settings?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, fonts

I use the desktop app for Outlook 365. I have been using quick steps for years and have never had a problem until recently.  For the last couple of weeks or so, whenever I use a quick step the font is 10pt, even though my default font size is 11pt as it always has been.  I have checked stationary and fonts settings in the Outlook option menu, I have checked the normalemail.dotm file, and I checked my outlook 365 settings on the web.  All show the default size is still 11pt.  Yet my quick steps still default to 10pt.  I am not sure how this started happening, and I have co-workers who are experiencing the same issue.  How do I fix this so that it uses my default size?  The point of the quick step is to save time, but when I have to go back and change the font size on every email, it kind of defeats the purpose.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can provide the specific quick steps? (Preferably screenshot)

Comment: It is mainly happening on the quick steps that are set up to reply to other emails.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test in Outlook 365(version is as shown in the below figure), and i set the default size to 11pt of **Replying or forwarding messages** Font settings, when i click the quick step(just reply the email), the default size will be 11pt, which didn't reproduce your issue. Please check if you have set the correct font.

Outlook 365 version:
[image]

**Replying or forwarding messages** Font settings:

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.